# Thinkpad T510 - ActiveRotate feature? (Like the X220t)

Tags: thinkpad

I was wondering if any one who owns a T510 (or similar model with NVIDIA graphics) has managed to get automatic screen rotations working similar to the ActiveRotate feature found on Thinkpad X220t models.

What I mean is, when I turn my laptop on its side, I'd like it to automatically rotate the screen to portrait mode. I realize this can be done manually, but it would be nice to have it done as soon as the whole computer is put onto its side.

Thanks in advance,

Brandon

Comment: Here is a source for an explanation of the ActiveRotate feature: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Active_Rotate

Comment: I have to ask how on earth you're using it sideways.  This isn't exactly a tiny laptop.  Anyway, I think this is done through ACPI and the signal that it looks for simply isn't there - there's nothing to trigger the event.  There may be some sort of workaround but I'll be somewhat surprised if somebody produces one.